# How do I install a Scilab toolbox in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, scilab, toolbox

I installed Scilab using the apt-get and now I would like to install this toolbox: http://sourceforge.net/projects/data-comm/

I tried this:

```
tomsInstall('/home/martin/Dropbox/universidad/Intro distribuidos/TP6/datacomm.tar.gz')
atomsExtract: The extraction of the archive '/home/martin/Dropbox/universidad/Intro distribuidos/TP6/datacomm.tar.gz' has failed.
 !--error 10000 

at line      51 of function atomsError called by :  
at line      82 of function atomsExtract called by :  
at line     153 of function atomsInstall called by :  
TP6/datacomm.tar.gz'
```

And it's obviously not working, any clues?

Answer (score 1):

You must use `tar xzf datacomm.tar.gz` to extract this archive, then follow the instructions in the README text file (I have not enough reputation to comment).